# how does the js coercion work in some cases

Tags: javascript, coercion

I've learnt that converting null and undefined to string via String() method, the result will be 'null' and 'undefined', but why does String([null,undefined]) return ','

String(null); //'null'

String(undefined); //'undefined'

String([null, undefined]); //','     why?

Comment: Because `[null, undefined].toString()` = `,`

Comment: Could you please explain it in more details?

Comment: `String([ ... ])` calls `[ ... ].toString()` ([Step 2b](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-string-constructor-string-value)) which calls [`.join()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.join) ([Step 2+4](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.tostring)) -> Step 7c: _"If `element` is **`undefined` or `null`, let `next` be the empty String**; otherwise, let next be ? `ToString(element)`."_

Comment: Thanks a lot -Andreas. This works only with arrays. Am I right?

Comment: @andreas please stop answering in the comments ;)

Comment: @JonasWilms I haven't found a suitable dupe and a "read the specification" is not really an answer. But yes, that could have been another copy&paste community wiki answer.